# Phone Gap - Working on Simulator not on real device

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cordova

I don't know why this is happening . I have an phone 5 IOS 6.0.1 , when I'm running an app in simulator its running totally fine and every thing is showing up correctly and all links are working in the app..

But when I'm running it on Iphone its not showing up anything

[image] Failed to load webpage with error: The requested URL was not found on this server.

1) WWW folder is on right place inside the xcode and all files were copied correctly

2) First it was not running with architecture armv7s , i removed that after that it starts running on Iphone 5.

Comment: And what is "the requested URL"? May we see some code?

Comment: yeah sure , all files and folders are local to the app and stored inside www folder.
/Users/xyz/Desktop/Hello/www/css/jquery-mobile.css

Comment: For images I'm referencing like this 
/Users/xyz/Desktop/Hello/www/img/fb-login-button-new.png

If i open index.html in browser , its opening correctly and even in simulator too

Comment: you are answering yourself, the files are in the computer, not in the device, in the devices you can not access any files that's out of the application sandbox

Comment: How to put files into the device ?? will you please help

Comment: You could have the app download them on launch?

Answer (score 0):

Found the Answer.

Actually i was giving a wrong reference to the files and files were added wrongly inside the www folder. So i deleted all the files and added them again. Gave the local path for images , CSS and JS files and it worked